# Given 3 columns, a tcolorbox box starts in column 2. Why?

Tags: multicol, tcolorbox

Consider the following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
A is for Amy who fell down the stairs.

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

This is how it is rendered as pdf:

[image: breakable + multicol]

Why does the box start in the second column? How can I force it to start following the paragraph in the first column?

---

**A suggested explanation and my reservations thereto**

According to [Prof. Sturm's comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372164/given-3-columns-a-tcolorbox-box-starts-in-column-2-why#comment919610_372171), the behavior described above is not a bug; it results from the fact that

> `tcolorbox` does not know the available space inside a `multicols` environment.

But then consider the modified document obtained from the original one by reducing the tcolorbox's contents to the first sentence of the paragraph. The resulting pdf is as follows:

[image: shorter breakable + multicol]

If `tcolorbox` does not know the available space inside a `multicols` environment then why doesn't the tcolorbox start on the second column as before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are limits to what is possible in the interaction between two packages that both try to split a galley into columns without knowing much about each other, e.g., if `multicol` runs in balancing mode it does its balancing only after any `tcolorbox` inside has done its magic and thus will only see the breakpoints left by `tcolorbox`. Thus there is not much chance for automation unless the two packages are really interconnected (ie one implements the features of the other) which is not going to happen.
So that means here one has to supply the breakpoints for `tcolorbox`manually.

However, in the case of `multicols*` the situation is somewhat different as `tcolorbox` could know the available space. It does however simply assumes that it will be `\textheight` and therefore shows the undesired behavior.
Don't think one can call this a **bug** but it is an unnecessary limitation given that `tcolorbox`already tries to be `multicol`-aware.

Fact is that the available space is known (or could be): it is `\@colroom` minus whatever has been already typeset in the multicol environment, i.e., `\pagetotal`(as long as we are in the first column). If we are further down then some level of adjustement is needed but as the code below shows, it seems to be doable.

Now I don't know much about tcolorbox internals (in fact I have looked at the code for the first time today) so my "fix" may need some further adjustments, but the direction it probably ok.

So here is the code and test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newif\iftcb@latermulticol  % are we in a later column?

% remaining height
\def\tcb@comp@h@page{%
  \tcb@breakat@next%
  \ifdim\tcb@breakat@dim>0pt\relax%
    \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\tcb@breakat@dim-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
  \else%
    \ifx\kvtcb@float\@empty%
      \iftcb@multicol%
      %
      % currently tcolorbox always assumes that \textheight is available
      %
      %        \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\textheight-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
      %
      % but we do know what is available inside a multicol:
      %
      % it is \@colroom minus what is already set (which is \pagetotal)
      %
      % However this is only true for the first column as multicol scans all
      % column material and only then breaks it into columns
      % So for the next columns we need to tell tcolorbox that the value
      % is \@colroom (without any substractions)
      %
      % Thus we distinguish the two cases via a boolean
      %
        \iftcb@latermulticol
          \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\@colroom-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
        \else
          \tcb@latermulticoltrue
          \ifdim\pagegoal=16383.99998pt
            \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\@colroom-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
          \else%
      %
          % If we start not in the first column then \pagetotal is already
          % the material for more than a column so we substract \@colroom
          % until we are in range (which is not quite accurate but close)
      %    
            \@tempdima\pagetotal
            \@whiledim \@tempdima>\@colroom \do{\advance\@tempdima-\@colroom}%
            \tcb@comp@compress%
            \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\@colroom-\@tempdima+\tcb@compress@height -\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
          \fi%
        \fi
      %
      % end of mod
      %
      \else%
        \ifdim\pagegoal=16383.99998pt
          \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\vsize-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}% detects floating objects
        \else%
          \tcb@comp@compress%
          \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\pagegoal-\pagetotal+\tcb@compress@height-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\textheight-\kvtcb@shrinkbreakgoal}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
  A is for Amy who fell down the stairs.

  \begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols*}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots
  Starting with tcolorbox in the second column \ldots

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols*}


The balancing multicol of course still fails without manual help as
that would require both packages interact with each other

\begin{multicols}{3}
  A is for Amy who fell down the stairs.

  \begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols}

some more text

\end{document}
```

If we typeset this then we get the following three pages:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your patch sounds very promising to me. I will test it in the near future and I intend to incorporate it into `tcolorbox`, if no unexpected problems arise :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm it could probably be streamlined a bit as far as the logic is concerned.  Also I haven't really checked what `\tcb@comp@compress` does, only guessed from the name :-)

Comment: `\tcb@comp@compress` inserts (optionally) `\pageshrink` or something similar. Inside `multicols`, I would rather omit this for safety reasons.

Comment: I played with the code and some adaptions. For single page examples, the result is superior to the current implementation. But, if the example spreads over several pages and the space for `multicol` on the first page is lower than `\textheight`, a new problem arises. The first two boxes of the following page are too short since `\@colroom` still contains the space value from the (smaller) first page. Currently, my only idea is to detect the page break by labelling and to replace `\col@room` by `\textheight` on a page break. I'm open to any better idea ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find a stable solution for multi-pages where the first page contains some stuff before `multicol`. I have to postpone further experiments for at least a week, but I will come back to it later.

Comment: I incorporated a modified version of your patch into the new `tcolorbox` version and I added a new answer based on the new version.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Frank Mittelbachs patch, I experimented a lot to get an algorithm which can do the breaking inside a `multicols` environment in a fully automated way. But I found too many situations which fool an automatism in a way which is worse than not having such an automatism. Meanwhile, I do not see any success in future.

Nevertheless, a half-automated breaking is possible which is superior to the old implementation. I adapted the patch of Frank Mittelbach and implemented a changed version for `tcolorbox` from version `4.10 (2017/07/05)`.

The main (new) characteristics are:

- The default break height is the **current** column height at begin of breaking. If the height column height changes from one page to the next, the default break height is not changed (actually, it changes, but not for the first column on the next page).
- The height of the first box part is estimated as in Frank Mittelbachs patch. There is a fair change that this estimation gives a too-large value causing the first box part to slip from the current column to the next one.

To compensate the possible named shortcuts, a `break at` can be added. `break at` also was modified to support easier corrections.

Let's look at some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
  A is for Amy who fell down the stairs.

  \begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable]
    \lipsum[1-2]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols*}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
  \lipsum[1-3]

  \begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable]
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols*}

The two examples above worked without manual help, but this will be true
only for lucky situations. If a multicols environment starts on one page
with previous content (like this one) and continues to a second page,
the automatism will fail.
In this case, use the \texttt{break at} option:

\begin{multicols*}{3}
  A is for Amy who fell down the stairs.
  \lipsum[1-2]

  \begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum},breakable,height fixed for=first and middle,
    break at=-\baselineskip/0pt/\textheight,
  ]
    \lipsum[1-5]
  \end{tcolorbox}

  B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The first two `multicols*` environments with an embedded breakable `tcolorbox` did not need any manual corrections, but the third one is tricky.
Here, the following was added to get the (good) result:

```
break at=-\baselineskip/0pt/\textheight
```

The meaning is as follows:

- `-\baselineskip`: The first column is sized according to the estimated space minus one `\baselineskip`, because the actual space is smaller than the estimated one. Prior to version `4.10 (2017/07/05)`, negative values had the same meaning as `0pt`.
- `0pt`: The second column is sized to get the **current** column height. Prior to version `4.10 (2017/07/05)`, `0pt` meant `\textheight`.
- `\textheight`: The third column and all following columns are sized to `\textheight`, because on our example page 4 the height of the columns changes.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a great improvement. Two questions, though. (1) I get the impression that the settings `break at=-\baselineskip/0pt/\textheight` will normally be the ones the user would like to use, then why can't it be the default? My only guess is that your code isn't able to figure out the total number of columns and the ordinal number of the column where the tcolorbox begins. Then maybe you can add a simplified way of informing your code about this, e.g. `col_pos=2/3` meaning that there are 3 column on this page and the tcolor box starts at the 2nd one.

Comment: (2) What holds you back from providing a fully automated solution? Is there anything that Frank Mittelbach can change in his implementation of multicols or in the API he exposes that would enable you to do it? Or is it something more fundamental than that?

Comment: @EvanAad As I said, a fully automated solution does not work stable. I invested a lot of time to tweak the algorithm, but the algortihm variants all fail too often. I think the problem is fundamental and neither Frank Mittelbach nor I can solve it.

Comment: @EvanAad `break at=-\baselineskip/0pt/\textheight` is a good start, but depending on the situation it may be `break at=-2\baselineskip/0pt/\textheight`, `break at=-\baselineskip/0pt/0pt/\textheight`, `break at=-\baselineskip/\textheight`, etc. ...

Comment: So if *I* were to start writing a new package from scratch to replace `multicols`, there's nothing I could do to enable you to automate the flow of tcolorboxes in the columns provided by my package?

Comment: @EvanAad You never should say never :-) But the base of the problem is that a breakable `tcolorbox`+`multicols` technically is a `\vsplit` in a `\vsplit` which is not really supported by TeX. The same problem exists for a breakable `tcolorbox` inside a breakable `tcolorbox` which one should never use...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a paragraph before the `tcolorbox` inside a `multicol` environment breaks the way `tcolorbox` computes the height of the first fragment and places it on the second column. I think this a bug but I'll wait for other comments/opinions. In the mean time the undesired behaviour can be avoid with a manually computed `break at=` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
A is for Amy who fell down the stairs.

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Lorem Ipsum}, breakable, break at=18cm/0pt]
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

B is for Basil assaulted by bears.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'I don't know what happens with *your* code'? Does my code work on your computer?

Comment: @EvanAad You code is correct, my redaction was not. I've edited my answer to express it better.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just the way it is ... `tcolorbox` does not know the available space inside a `multicols` environment. And `multicol` does not know how to balance the break points for `tcolorbox`. Sadly, it has to be done manually.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks for your reply, Dr. Sturm. But if `tcolorbox` doesn't know the available space inside a `multicol` environment, how does it manage to break the box so well between the 2nd and the 3rd columns in my original post?

Comment: @Ignasi: Based on what did you choose the values `18cm/0pt` for the `break at` option? What does this option mean, anyhow?

Comment: @EvanAad Inside a multicol environment, the default assumed space is the `\textheight`. After the complete box is broken into several parts with `\textheight` and the remaining last one, the boxed are arranged by multicol. So, if the first break is adapted manually (if needed), the overall result is quite pleasing. Still, the first break remains to be set manually.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm as far as I can see it can be automated with a little bit more code in `\tcb@comp@h@page`

Comment: @Ignasi: I'm going to do a somewhat unethical move and reassign the checkmark to [Frank Mittelbach's reply](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372362/21685) at the unavoidable consequence of removing it from yours. I apologize from the bottom of my heart, but I hope that if you read his answer you will agree with my decision.

Comment: @EvanAad No problem at all. In fact my answer was just a workaround that could work while waiting for better solutions.

Comment: @Ignasi You may be interested in my new answer based on the modifications done for `tcolorbox 4.10`. I added some explanations what changed with the new version.